# Can I use DDR3 SO-DIMM instead of SO-DIMM L on J3455 Mobo?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

Hi I want to buy a mobo with J3455 (Gigabyte GA-J3455N-D3H), but it supports only DDR3L SO-DIMM. I got 2 SO-DIMM DDR3 (without L). Can I use those instead?

P.S. I know that if it is written DDR3L only means that those can be incompatible, but are there any chance that they will work?

Comment: "I know that if it is written DDR3L only means that those can be incompatible" - It actually means they are low voltage.  So unless the modules you purchase support that lower voltage (this is unlikely) then the modules you purchase are unlikely to work.  Since you told us nothing about either modules, its not possible to properly answer this question, so you should edit your question and supply that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most motherboards with the J3455 support both DDR3L and DDR3, but if the particular motherboard you have in mind specifically omits the information on supporting regular DDR3, then it is most likely that it will not.

The support is completely dependent on the motherboard manufacturer and what voltages the hardware & UEFI (eg. "BIOS") supports. So if you're thinking of a Asus or Asrock motherboard+CPU combo, for example, it is most likely that you can use regular DDR3. (But it would help with the answer if you specified the manufacturer and model in question - if you have one in mind...)

Comment: Mobo is GA-J3455N-D3H, @DocWeird. I suppose it will not. 10x for the answer.